# I have a tab in mysite.com/user which I don't know where it's coming from?

Tags: users

I have a tab in mysite.com/user called "Evaluaciones" but I don't know why is there. The link for this tab is `user/1/webform-submissions-por-user` then I guess it is generated by the webform module, but I already disabled this module and the tab is stil there.

How can I trace it? How Can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure you disabled the Webform module (and not one of it's sub-modules maybe)? It doesn't make sense that a tab provided by a disabled module would show up, unless you have some aggressive cache happening somewhere? Or maybe grep your codebase for `webform-submissions-por-user` and see if it's something in custom code...

Comment: Yes I am. I did it with drush. I disabled webform and all modules that depends on webform module. The tab is still there. I think it has to be another module which is using the same name for the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Tab Tammer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module to hide it.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy 
>   re-ordering, hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. 
>   You can also rename tab labels.

Comment: This will not address any permission problems if you are trying to remove the functionality from the user.  The user could still manually goto the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Its coming from the webform module.  I believe if you turn off the ability to allow users to view previous submissions it will go away.

Comment: I'm 100% sure webform and its permissions are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide using [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) hook.

```
function menualter_menu_alter(&$items) {
unset($items['user/%user/webform-submissions-por-user']);
}
```

Comment: I just created the hook: 'function utilities_menu_alter(&$items) {
unset($items['user/%user/webform-submissions-por-user']);
}' but the tab is still there. The full path of the link is 'http://localhost/mysite/user/1/webform-submissions-por-user'

Comment: Did you got the solution ? If not then try to clear the cache and view it again. :-)

Comment: I clear all caches but... still there. Maybe the path in my hook is wrong?

Comment: Your path seems right there is no problem in your code

Comment: The hook is not invoked, I tried to output dpm('hello') and I get nothing. 'function utilities_menu_alter(&$items) { dpm('hello'); }'In the same module I have a hook_form_alter() hook and dpm('hello') works (just to be sure that dmp() works)

Comment: If possible try to uninstall and install module and any other hooks are working ? like **hook_form_alter()** etc..